# Как сделать ожидание ответа от клиента

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть логика проверки пользователя.

```
...
const i = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
    i.question(`Please, visit an url ${url} and enter a verifier: ', verifier => {
        i.close();
        process.stdin.destroy();
        ...
```

Сейчас я ввожу код в консоль.

Для авторизации у меня есть роутер `http://localhost:8081/api/authorization/`

Как можно переделать чтобы сервер ждал когда пользователь нажмет на кнопку и мне пришел код `http://localhost:8081/api/authorization?12345`.

Comment: это что за фреймворк?

Comment: @ThisMan Это `nodejs` и встроенные в него `readline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const readline = require('readline')
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

rl.on('line', function (line) {
   // В line - то что ввел пользователь
   // Здесь можно выполнить запрос или вызвать callback функцию
})
```